# SQL querying of a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a ruby on rails application which runs on Postgres database.

(application is not mine by the way, just trying to mess around with and learn more)

So, if I run a simple query such as this:

`SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY users.id ASC LIMT 1`

I get this:

`SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY users.id ASC LIMT 1`

I've been getting that error pretty consistently regardless of any query I run, no matter how simple or complicated.

Why?

EDIT 1

Btw, wanted to mention that this query is run in the console ... fyi.

Even a simple query like this: `SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1` gets me the same error, regardless.

EDIT 2

This is what I get:

```
psql (9.0.13, server 9.3.1)
WARNING: psql version 9.0, server version 9.3.
     Some psql features might not work.
Type "help" for help.

nameofApp=# SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1
nameofApp-# 
nameOfApp-# 
nameofApp-#
```

The hashmarks continue when I press Enter. It doesn't seem to perform the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect to Postgresql by psql NAMEOFDATABASEHERE

Then end all your queries with a semicolon.

```
    select * from users; (ENTER)
```

If you don't type the semicolon the interpreter keeps waiting for more statements and you will be greeted by the next hash sign when pressing enter.

Hope it helps!

Comment: it does help, at least this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this in the db console. Try `rails db` from the commandline. Or for an equivalent result in the console try: `User.first`

Comment: sorry for taking so long in getting back on this. Just tried rails db, and I do get `psql (9.0.13, server 9.3.1)` etc.. So, tried `SELECT * FROM user LIMIT 1` again, but it doesn't do anything. it just keeps showing the hashmark (#) when I hit enter again and again. Why?

Comment: please look at Edit 2 in my post above for a clearer look at what I'm talking about.